# Pascal's Triangle Scala: Compute elements of Pascal's triangle using tail recursive approach

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, tail-recursion

In Pascal's Triangle the number at the edge of the triangle are all 1, and each number inside the triangle is the sum of the two numbers above it. A sample Pascal's triangle would look like below.

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

I wrote a program that computes the elements of Pascal's triangle using below technique.

```
/**
* Can I make it tail recursive???
*
* @param c column
* @param r row
* @return 
*/
def pascalTriangle(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  if (c == 0 || (c == r)) 1
  else
    pascalTriangle(c-1, r-1) + pascalTriangle(c, r - 1)
}
```

So, for example if

```
i/p: pascalTriangle(0,2)  
o/p: 1.

i/p: pascalTriangle(1,3)  
o/p: 3.
```

Above program is correct and giving the correct output as expected. My question is, is it possible to write tail recursive version of above algorithm? How?

Comment: Yes, the same way you would write any tail-recursive function. You need your own in-heap stack of remaining operations, an an inner accumulator for keeping track of the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
def pascalTriangle(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(c0: Int, r0: Int, pred: Array[Int], cur: Array[Int]): Int = {
    cur(c0) = (if (c0 > 0) pred(c0 - 1) else 0) + (if (c0 < r0) pred(c0) else 0)

    if ((c0 == c) && (r0 == r)) cur(c0)
    else if (c0 < r0) loop(c0 + 1, r0, pred, cur)
    else loop(0, r0 + 1, cur, new Array(_length = r0 + 2))
  }

  if ((c == 0) && (r == 0)) 1
  else loop(0, 1, Array(1), Array(0, 0))
}
```

or

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def pascalTriangle(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  def hlp(c: Int, r: Int): TailRec[Int] =
    if (c == 0 || (c == r)) done(1)
    else for {
      x <- tailcall(hlp(c - 1, r - 1))
      y <- tailcall(hlp(c, r - 1))
    } yield (x + y)

  hlp(c, r).result
}
```

or

```
import cats.free.Trampoline
import cats.free.Trampoline.{defer, done}
import cats.instances.function._

def pascalTriangle(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  def hlp(c: Int, r: Int): Trampoline[Int] =
    if (c == 0 || (c == r)) done(1)
    else for {
      x <- defer(hlp(c - 1, r - 1))
      y <- defer(hlp(c, r - 1))
    } yield (x + y)

  hlp(c, r).run
}
```

http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stackless-scala-with-free-monads.html

Comment: any thoughts on the benefits of this seemingly complex recursive approach vs. iterative?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer Which recursive approach are you talking about and which iterative one are you talking about?

Comment: this example generates a whole row instead of one cell: https://leetcode.com/problems/pascals-triangle/discuss/38141/My-concise-solution-in-Java

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer This is Java, not Scala.

Answer (score 0):

A couple optimizations to @DmytroMitin 's 1st solution:

1. Replace `if ((c == 0) && (r == 0)) 1` with `if (c == 0 || c == r) 1`.
2. Take advantage of the symmetry in the triangle and use c's reflected value if it is greater than half of r.

With these optimizations, the number of calls to `loop` to draw a triangle with 30 rows is reduced from 122,760 to 112,375 (with #1) to 110,240 (with both #1 and #2) calls (without memoization).

```
  def pascalTail(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
    val cOpt = if (c > r/2) r - c else c
    def loop(col: Int, row: Int, previous: Array[Int], current: Array[Int]): Int = {
      current(col) = (if (col > 0) previous(col - 1) else 0) + (if (col < row) previous(col) else 0)

      if ((col == cOpt) && (row == r)) current(col)
      else if (col < row) loop(col + 1, row, previous, current)
      else loop(0, row + 1, current, new Array(_length = row + 2))
    }

    if (c == 0 || c == r) 1
    else loop(0, 1, Array(1), new Array(_length = 2))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a code to quickly comprehend the tail recursion logic for Pascal Triangle and stumbled upon this thread. However, thought of also having a readable solution which can shout out the logic clearly. Below is my draft attempted solution but can further be improved (for readability). From an optimization/performance standpoint it is taken care I guess.

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  if(c > r) throw new RuntimeException

  def symmetricalGet(row: Array[Int]) = {
    val lastIndex = row.size - 1
    lastIndex match {
      case l if l >= c => row(c)
      case l => {
        val diffFromCenter = c - l
        val mirrorIdx = l - diffFromCenter
        row(mirrorIdx)
      }
    }
  }

  def computeRow(acc: Array[Int], isRowIdxOdd: Boolean): Array[Int] = {
    val cArray = 1 +: acc
      .sliding(2)
      .map(_.sum)
      .toArray

    isRowIdxOdd match {
      case true => cArray :+ cArray.last
      case _ => cArray
    }
  }

  @tailrec
  def goNextRow(row: Int, acc: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1)): Array[Int] = {
    val isOdd = row % 2 != 0
    if(row == r) computeRow(acc, isOdd)
    else goNextRow(row + 1, computeRow(acc, isOdd))
  }

  if(c == 0 || r <= 1 || c == r) 1
  else symmetricalGet(goNextRow(2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **tail recursion** solution. It is written in **Scala Language.**

Each pascal number(c, r), (c is column, r is row) is generated by two number (c-1, r-1) + (c, r-1).
My solution is to save all the pascal numbers into a List, then calculate one number from the List in one function call.
If the number is edge number then it is 1, otherwise push two upper row numbers into the list.

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int =
  @tailrec
  def pascal_tail(sum: Int, numbers: List[(Int, Int)]): Int =
    numbers match
      // Every pascal number's final value is the sum of many 1
      case Nil => sum
      case head :: tail =>
        val (c, r) = head
        // If the number is edge number, its value is 1
        if c == 0 || c == r then pascal_tail(sum + 1, tail)
        // If it is not edge number, add two upper numbers into the list
        else pascal_tail(sum, (c-1, r-1)::(c, r-1)::tail)
  pascal_tail(0, List((c, r)))
```